# Importar banco de dados sem os dados das tabelas diretamente pelo Mysql

Tags: mysql

Estou precisando importar para o Mysql uma base de dados muito grande. Pelo phpmyadmin quase parou o servidor. Então tentei diretamente pelo Mysql usando o comando:

```
source /var/www/html/sistema/basedados.sql
```

Ok, consegui importar, mas com todos os dados de todas as tabelas, porém gostaria de saber se tem algum meio de importar pelo Mysql o banco de dados somente com as tabelas, sem os dados. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 1):

Na hora que você exportar o banco, você pode escolher para exportar somente a estrutura do banco, ou seja, ele não exportará nenhum dado, somente a estrutura das tabelas.

Abaixo tem uma imagem mostrando como exportar somente a estrutura pelo phpmyadmin, você vai em exportar -> export method, clica em personalizado, e ai você desabilita o campo dos dados e é só exportar. Se o banco não estiver no phpmyadmin você deve procurar uma opção parecida com essa, que acredito eu que já deva estar implementado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -1):

Ai você tem que separar as linhas de criação e as de insert em arquivos separados, assim quando quiser importar só as tabelas você importa por exemplo o arquivo tabelas.sql e vice-versa

tabelas.sql:

```
CREATE TABLE fulano(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(150),
    senha CHAR(32)
);
```

inserir.sql

```
INSERT INTO fulano(nome, email, senha) VALUES ('José',   
'jose@email.com', MD5('jose123'));

INSERT INTO fulano(nome, email, senha) VALUES ('Maria', 
'maria@email.com', MD5('maria321'));
```

Comment: Olá Anderson. Na verdade estou querendo evitar isso, haja vista que o arquivo sql é muito grande, com várias tabelas e dados. Isso seria muito trabalhoso ter que abrir o arquivo e separar as tabelas dos dados, que não serão aproveitados. Gostaria de uma solução diretamente pelo SQL.